# How does the utility "sort" work? (why does it not work the way I think it should?)

Tags: sort

I have 2 text files:

```
$ cat /tmp/test1
"AAP" bar
"AEM" bar
"AA" bar
"AEO" bar
"A" bar

$ cat /tmp/test2
"AEM" foo
"AAP" foo
"A" foo
"AEO" foo
"AA" foo
```

I want to sort them

```
$ sort /tmp/test1
"AA" bar
"AAP" bar
"A" bar              <-- "A" is in position 3
"AEM" bar
"AEO" bar

$ sort /tmp/test2
"AA" foo
"AAP" foo
"AEM" foo
"AEO" foo
"A" foo              <-- "A" is in position 5
```

Why does `"A"` end up in **position 3 in `/tmp/test1`** and in **position 5 in `/tmp/test2`**?

My expectation is that **each character per column** will be compared.

As such, when comparing column 3, `'A'`, `'E'` and `'"'` will be compared against each other, and this would be the ultimate determinant in the final sort order of this test data.

Clearly my expectation is wrong, so how does `sort` work, if not in the way I expected?

Is there command line option to `sort` or some other utility I can use to get the sort order I desire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have collation locale changed. The behavior you describe is typical to `en_US` and many other locales. Fix with:

```
LC_ALL=C   sort  /tmp/test1
```

More in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531674/linux-sort-unexpected-output

Comment: Or just `LC_ALL=C sort x`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, I've edited that into the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly it only looks at alphabetical characters? Therefore, in the case of `A` the next alphabetical character is the `b` from bar.

Comment: I think you're right.  From `man sort`:        `*** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order  that  uses
       native byte values.`  So possibly there is a locale specified that causes sort to behave like this.